# Different versions of node but not detectable by apt

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to install 'yo' to use 'yo code' so I need the latest version of node but I have two node(s), one usable without root permissions and another one that needs it but if I try to remove the node using apt, so apt remove or apt autoremove, it doesn't detect the node, as in photo.

[image: example]

Comment: apt only knows about things you installed using apt. That's normal and expected; if you install node using something other than apt, or you installed it under a different name (say, `node12`), then apt won't know that that's what you meant when you said "node".

Comment: The question isn't topical here -- it's more about `apt` (a generic sysadmin tool rather than a software development tool) than about node or about writing code -- but if it _were_, I'd ask you for information on _where those copies of `node` are installed_. Comparing the output of `command -v node` with that of `sudo which node` is a place to start.

Comment: Once you've found the executables, you can use `dpkg -S /path/to/node` (substituting the real path given to you by `which` or `command -v`) to find out which, if any, package each executable belongs to.

Comment: Also, for the future, don't post screenshots of text -- just copy-and-paste the text itself. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta]. [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) describes how to do this and make it come out looking right.